# why use a const non-reference when const reference lifetime is the length of the current scope

Tags: c++

So in c++ if you assign the return value of a function to a const reference then the lifetime of that return value will be the scope of that reference. E.g.

```
MyClass GetMyClass()
{
    return MyClass("some constructor");
}

void OtherFunction()
{
    const MyClass& myClass = GetMyClass(); // lifetime of return value is until the end            
                                           // of scope due to magic const reference
    doStuff(myClass);
    doMoreStuff(myClass);
}//myClass is destructed
```

So it seems that wherever you would normally assign the return value from a function to a const object you could instead assign to a const reference. Is there ever a case in a function where you would want to not use a reference in the assignment and instead use a object? Why would you ever want to write the line:

```
const MyClass myClass = GetMyClass();
```

Edit: my question has confused a couple people so I have added a definition of the GetMyClass function

Edit 2: please don't try and answer the question if you haven't read this: 
http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/

Comment: I don't know why you would want to do that? Other than, perhaps, the value returned isn't a reference anyway, so there is still a copy being made [even if that copy is an unnamed temporary object, generated by the compiler to hold the returned object]... Without seeing the return type of `GetMyClass()`, I can't say for sure.

Comment: If there is _any_ chance of the function ever returning by value, you don't want to use a reference, because it is misleading.  And if the function is guaranteed to return a reference, then the choice becomes one of whether you want to use the object to which the return value refers (including taking into account that it might have a shorter lifetime than the local reference), or whether you want your own object, with its defined lifetime.

Comment: @JamesKanze in the example I put it does return by value.

Comment: @dan In which case, there is no reason to use the reference.

Comment: @dan And I've read the article you refer to, but it doesn't seem to say anything that we don't all know anyway.  It doesn't say anything as to why someone would want to do anything like that; if it did, it would have to say that there is no reason, and that it is just bad programming practice.

Comment: @JamesKanze read the guru question.

Comment: @TobiasLangner I have.  It's still something very widely known, and not relevant to the question here.

Comment: it is very relevant. The guru question shows you that you can prevent slicing if you take the const reference of a base class instead of the value of a base class. And no - it is not widely known.

Comment: If polymorphism is involved, the function in question will have to return a reference or a pointer, or it slices.

Comment: no, it doesn't. If it returns by value and you get the return value by const reference to its base class, it never slices (according to the standard). Just try my example below with your favorite compiler (except Digital Mars prior to 8.5.1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the function returns an object (rather than a reference), making a copy in the calling function is necessary [although optimisation steps may be taken that means that the object is written directly into the resulting storage where the copy would end up, according to the "as-if" principle].

In the sample code `const MyClass myClass = GetMyClass();` this "copy" object is named `myclass`, rather than a temporary object that exists, but isn't named (or visible unless you look at the machine-code). In other words, whether you declare a variable for it, or not, there will be a `MyClass` object inside the function calling `GetMyClass` - it's just a matter of whether you make it visible or not.

Edit2:
The `const` reference solution will appear similar (not identical, and this really just written to explain what I mean, you can't actually do this):

```
 MyClass __noname__ = GetMyClass();
 const MyClass &myclass = __noname__;
```

It's just that the compiler generates the `__noname__` variable behind the scenes, without actually telling you about it.

By making a `const MyClass myclass` the object is made visible and it's clear what is going on (and that the `GetMyClass` is returning a COPY of an object, not a reference to some already existing object).

On the other hand, if `GetMyClass` does indeed return a reference, then it is certainly the correct thing to do.

IN some compilers, using a reference may even add an extra memory read when the object is being used, since the reference "is a pointer" [yes, I know, the standard doesn't say that, but please before complaining, do me a favour and show me a compiler that DOESN'T implement references as pointers with extra sugar to make them taste sweeter], so to use a reference, the compiler should read the reference value (the pointer to the object) and then read the value inside the object from that pointer. In the case of the non-reference, the object itself is "known" to the compiler as a direct object, not a reference, saving that extra read. Sure, most compilers will optimise such an extra reference away MOST of the time, but it can't always do that.

Comment: Why is making a copy necessary if the object returns an object rather than a reference?

Comment: And where does that object end up? The copy I'm talking about is to the temporary storage in the receiving function - it is either an "unnamed object" or a named object [technically, the compiler would sometimes make TWO copies, but the Return Value Optimisation allows the compiler to make that into one copy].

Comment: That copy is most probably elided per [class.copy]/31. However, it needs to be copyable.

Comment: If the copy is elided, it's done in the function itself. There MUST be storage for the `MyClass` object in `OtherFunction` - it may be that the `GetMyClass` function just writes straight into the storage passed by the compiler as an optimisation. Where else would the object be stored? What Herb Sutter says is simply that the copied object will remain until the `const` reference goes out of scope. But a string object exists inside `g` - it just hasn't got a name and isn't "visible". So, in other words, both solutions take the same space and code, with a potential for extra access in references.

Comment: "There MUST be storage for the `MyClass` object in `OtherFunction`" Yes, I didn't disagree. It's just I disagree with "making a copy is necessary": as you said, the compiler can directly write into this object. (That's one of the two copies that can be avoided.) However, "it's necessary that a copy *can* be made" is perfectly fine with copy elision [class.temporary]/1

Comment: @MatsPetersson More important than the extra dereference: if the compiler really treats this as a reference, it has to take into account that other functions might have a non-const reference to the object, and could modify it.  (I don't think any compilers are that dumb, and I would be very surprised if any generated different code in the case where the return type isn't a reference.

Comment: @JamesKanze: That only applies to when the object is being returned as a reference, right?

Comment: @MatsPetersson It depends.  If the compiler recognizes that the function returns by value, and treats the declaration as if it weren't a reference, then this doesn't apply.  If the compiler treats as a reference (extra pointer dereference, etc.) then it probably will apply.

Answer (score 1):

One reason would be that the reference may confuse other readers of your code. Not everybody is aware of the fact that the lifetime of the object is extended to the scope of the reference.

Comment: Or some readers can think that GetMyClass() return existing variable by refernce, not by value (for singletons, for example) and changes on this local object can will affect to other objects, that will be created somewhere another in code (later or in another threads). Even when reference is const, there can be some mutable values in internal state or concurrency runtime problems.

Comment: @user1837009 following on from that argument we should be passing by value everywhere rather than by const reference. I don't think anyone would argue that!

Comment: @user1837009 Perhaps more to the point: when using a reference returned by a function, you (and the compiler) has to take into account that the object might change its value in code elsewhere.

Comment: @JamesKanze but since the function is returning by value this is the only reference in the code to this object. So nothing else can modify it!

Comment: @dan But the compiler has to deduce that.  (I'm referring to Mats article where he says that most compilers implement references as a pointer under the hood.)

Comment: @JamesKanze in this special use case, it's a given fact. An object is returned by value, so the reference is bound to a temporary. Since it is a temporary, nobody else has access to it. This is a deduction - but no compiler will fail to do it.

Comment: @TobiasLangner In the same way as no compiler will in fact fail to merge all of the copies, and generate exactly the same code for the version with reference and with value (which means that the deduction isn't even necessary).

Answer (score 1):

The semantics of:

```
MyClass const& var = GetMyClass();
```

and

```
MyClass const var = GetMyClass();
```

are very different.  Generally speaking, you would only use the
first when the function itself returns a reference (and is
required to return a reference by its very semantics).  And you
know that you need to pay attention to the lifetime of the 
object (which is not under your control).  You use the second
when you want to own (a copy of) the object.  Using the second
in this case is misleading, can lead to surprises (if the
function also returns a reference to an object which is
destructed earlier) and is probably slightly less efficient
(although in practice, I would expect both to generate exactly
the same code if `GetMYClass` returns by value).

Comment: @dan Did you actually read what I wrote?  I said hat in the case where the function returns an object, both forms work, but the form with the reference is misleading (to the reader), and may be slightly less efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you want to achieve. The reason that `T const&` can be bound (on the stack) to a `T` (by value) which is returned from a function is to make it possible other function can take this temporary as an `T const&` argument. This prevents you from requirement to create overloads. But the returned value has to be constructed anyway.

But today (with C++11) you can use `const auto myClass = GetMyClass();`.

**Edit:**
As an excample of what can happen I will present something:

```
MyClass version_a();
MyClass const& version_b();

const MyClass var1 =version_a();
const MyClass var2 =version_b();

const MyClass var3&=version_a();
const MyClass var4&=version_b();

const auto    var5 =version_a();
const auto    var6 =version_b();
```

- `var1` is initialised with the result of `version_a()`
- `var2` is initialised with a copy of the object to which the reference returned by `version_b()` belongs
- `var3` holds a const reference to to the temoprary which is returned and extends its lifetime
- `var4` is initialised with the reference returned from `version_b()`
- `var5` same as `var1`
- `var6` same as `var4`

They are semanticall all different. `var3` works for the reason I gave above. Only `var5` and `var6` store automatically what is returned.

Comment: You can, but you probably don't want to.  C++ isn't Python, and in most cases, you want to name the type,  in order to be clear.

Comment: @JamesKanze I think one aspect of using `auto` is to choose the correct type. This works even if interfaces change. (I know, on the other hand I might break code which depends on certain types for overloading.)

Comment: `auto` can't choose the "correct" type, since the compiler doesn't know the type you want.  Spelling out the type is an important part of type safety, `auto` shuts it up.  There are exceptions, in common idioms like iterating (where the return type of `container.begin()` _is_ the type we want, by definition), but most of the time, `auto` translates into a loss of type safety.  (If you don't want the type safety, use Python.)

Comment: @JamesKanze I have written that I'm aware of this. But as far as I understand its not easy (or just impossible with lambdas) to spell out certain types. If somebody asks wether get the result of this partucular function by const reference or by value, than auto might help to choose the correct type. But I don't understand why you think I should use Python?

Comment: There are certainly cases where `auto` is appropriate.  But it's use should be limited to those cases; in some ways, the less you use it, the better (but I also use it for the return values of e.g. `v.begin()`, even though I do know how to spell them out).

Comment: @JamesKanze auto does not remove much type safety. The variable still has a defined type at compile time. The only safety that you lose is that the return type of a function could change to a different type and you won't recognize it if the different type has the same functions with the same signatures as the ones you call on that type. This may actually be intended as it eases template programming & refactoring.

Comment: `auto` means that you have no control over the type.  One obvious example: a function initially returns a `double`, and you need `double` for the calculations you do.  The function is changed to return `float`.  Suddenly, you start unaccountably loosing precision in your calculations.

Comment: having a double to accept the value would not change anything here: `double d = functionReturningDouble();` compiles as well as `double d = functionReturningFloat();` as float implicitly converts to double (even without a warning). This means that you would not notice in your example. Even worse. When debugging, your IDE will show d as double although in reality it contains only the significant bits of a float. With `auto d = ...` it would show d as float the moment the function returns a float. In short - in your example auto is slightly better than explicitly writing double.

Comment: @JamesKanze yes I know! I'm aware that the execution path is a kind of restricted by the types I am choosing. This is done by function obverloading. I'm aware that when using the wrong type something may be ambiguous at compile time. But if I need the result of a factory function (like in the qeustion) I normaly want exactly this type. If the factory changes to return a reference (possibly of a derived type), I don't want to make a copy (slicing).

Answer (score 0):

***Performance***

As most current compilers elide copies (and moves), both version should have about the same efficiency:

```
const MyClass& rMyClass = GetMyClass();
const MyClass  oMyClass = GetMyClass();
```

In the second case, either a copy or move is required semantically, but it can be elided per [class.copy]/31. A slight difference is that the first one works for non-copyable non-movable types.

It has been pointed out by Mats Petersson and James Kanze that accessing the reference might be slower for some compilers.

---

***Lifetime***

References *should* be valid during their entire scope just like objects with automatic storage are. This "*should*" of course is meant to be enforced by the programmer. So for the reader IMO there's no differences in the lifetimes implied by them. Although, if there was a bug, I'd probably look for dangling references (not trusting the original code / the lifetime claim for the reference).

In the case `GetMyClass` could ever be changed (reasonably) to return a reference, you'd have to make sure the lifetime of that object is sufficient, e.g.

```
SomeClass* p = /* ... */;

void some_function(const MyClass& a)
{
    /* much code with many side-effects */
    delete p;
    a.do_something();  // oops!
}

const MyClass& r = p->get_reference();
some_function(r);
```

---

***Ownership***

A variable directly naming an object like `const MyClass oMyClass;` clearly states *I own this object*. Consider `mutable` members: if you change them later, it's not immediately clear to the reader that's ok (for all changes) if it has been declared as a reference.

Additionally, for a reference, it's not obvious that the object its referring to *does not change*. A `const` reference only implies that *you* won't change the object, not that *nobody* will change the object(*). A programmer would have to *know* that this reference is the only way of referring to that object, by looking up the definition of that variable.

(*) Disclaimer: try to avoid unapparent side effects

Comment: Re your comments on performance: I've just run some quick tests on the compilers available to me (VC++ and g++), and even without optimization, both variants execute exactly the same number of copies.  Performance only enters into account when the function itself returns a reference (and then the semantics are completely different, and you must choose according to the semantics).

Answer (score 0):

there is a major implication regarding the destructor actually being called. Check Gotw88, Q3 and A3. I put everything in a small test program (Visual-C++, so forgive the stdafx.h)

```
// Gotw88.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

class A
{
protected:
    bool m_destroyed;
public:
    A() : m_destroyed(false) {}
    ~A() 
    { 
        if (!m_destroyed)
        {
            std::cout<<"A destroyed"<<std::endl;
            m_destroyed=true;
        }
    }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    ~B() 
    { 
        if (!m_destroyed)
        {
            std::cout<<"B destroyed"<<std::endl;
            m_destroyed=true;
        }
    }
};

B CreateB()
{
    return B();
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::cout<<"Reference"<<std::endl;
    {
        const A& tmpRef = CreateB();
    }
    std::cout<<"Value"<<std::endl;
    {
        A tmpVal = CreateB();
    }


    return 0;
}
```

The output of this little program is the following:

```
Reference
B destroyed
Value
B destroyed
A destroyed
```

Here a small explanation for the setup. B is derived from A, but both have no virtual destructor (I know this is a WTF, but here it's important). CreateB() returns B by value. Main now calls CreateB and first stores the result of this call in a const reference of type A. Then CreateB is called and the result is stored in a value of type A.

The result is interesting. First - if you store by reference, the correct destructor is called (B), if you store by value, the wrong one is called. Second - if you store in a reference, the destructor is called only once, this means there is only one object. By value results in 2 calls (to different destructors), which means there are 2 objects.

My advice - use the const reference. At least on Visual C++ it results in less copying. If you are unsure about your compiler, use and adapt this test program to check the compiler. How to adapt? Add copy / move constructor and copy-assignment operator.

---

I quickly added copy & assignment operators for class A & B

```
A(const A& rhs)
{
    std::cout<<"A copy constructed"<<std::endl;
}

A& operator=(const A& rhs)
{
    std::cout<<"A copy assigned"<<std::endl;
}
```

(same for B, just replace every capital A with B)

this results in the following output:

```
Reference
A constructed
B constructed
B destroyed
Value
A constructed
B constructed
A copy constructed
B destroyed
A destroyed
```

This confirms the results from above (please note, the A constructed results from B being constructed as B is derived from A and thus As constructor is called whenever Bs constructor is called).

Additional tests: Visual C++ accepts also the non-const reference with the same result (in this example) as the const reference. Additionally, if you use auto as type, the correct destructor is called (of course) and the return value optimization kicks in and in the end it's the same result as the const reference (but of course, auto has type B and not A).

Comment: This is bad advice: you should only use the reference if you want a reference (i.e. the called function returns a reference).  The compiler (including the VC++) generates the same code in both cases.

Comment: Your example program has undefined behavior, so it means nothing.  The advice you are giving is *bad*.  (And what's with the test of `m_destroyed`?  If it's ever false when you enter the destructor, you're screwed anyway.)

Comment: where has it undefined behavior? m_destroyed is only to not have double output in case the destructor of B is called. It has to call the destructor of A and I don't want an output in this case to clarify the result. Otherwise the output would be cluttered with the output from A's destructor which is not required.

Comment: Regarding const reference: accepting a value that is returned by a function in a reference seems to be (according to gotw88 linked above) part of the standard. The lifetime is extended. So I can accept it in a const reference if I require only a const reference for what I want to do (e.g. inspecting the object locally and not storing it somewhere). It seems to save me one copy here (in the usecase with inheritance of course).